# has_many , through: relationship count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I was hoping someone could help me with this, been trying to figure it out for a week now, I found a lot of examples, but as I'm new to rails I guess I keep making a mistake somewhere and I just cant find a right solution for my case.
So I have:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :subject_id, :created_at
   has_many :blogs_messages
   has_many :messages, through: :blogs_messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body, :created_at
   has_many :blogs_messages
   has_many :blogs, through: :blogs_messages
end

class BlogsMessages < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :message_id, :blog_id
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :message
end
```

Messages live in different Blogs(like Pink Blog, Green Blog, Maroon Blog etc), and Blogs live in Subjects (Dark Colors, Bright Colors etc)
Subjects have many Blogs, but Blogs can belong only to one Subject.

BlogsMessages is the connection between Messages and Blogs
what im trying to do is to show:
 top 3 Blogs (by amount of messages in them) within one Subject

so e.g. when I want to choose Subject Dark Colors it will show me:

```
    1.Maroon Blog: 46 messages
    2.Grey Blog: 13 messages
    3.Purple Blog: 12 messages
```

(There are 8 Blogs altogether in Subject Dark Colors.)

Could someone please help me with this, or at least point me in the right direction how to make it all work?

**Update:**

in my Blogs_controller now i have:

```
@blogs = Blog.joins(:blogs_messages => :message).select('blogs.*, COUNT(messages.id) AS message_count').group('blog_id').order('COUNT(messages.id) DESC').limit(3)
```

in my blogs view:

```
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <li><%= blog.name %>:  messages</li>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can work because I can't test it but it may help you:

```
 Blog.where(subject_id: subject.id)
      .joins(:blogs_messages => :message)
      .select('blogs.*, COUNT(messages.id) AS message_count')
      .group(:blog_id)
      .order('message_count DESC')
      .limit(3)
```

Also, in the view you could access to the new virtual attribute `message_count`:

```
 <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
   <li><%= blog.name %>: <%= blog.message_count %> messages</li>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you,i tried what you suggested.  i have that now in the blogs_controller as @blogs = Blog.includes(:messages_blogs => :message)....limit(3) and as you said <% @blogs.each do ..... %> in the view for blog  and this is the error i get :     BlogMysql2::Error: Unknown column 'message_count' in 'order clause': SELECT  DISTINCT `blogs`.id FROM `blogs` LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages_blogs` ON `messages_blogs`.`blog_id` = `blogs`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages` ON `messages`.`id` = `messages_blogs`.`message_id` GROUP BY blog.id ORDER BY message_count DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: Wow that's weird, are you sure you're using the `select` clause with the `COUNT(messages.id) AS message_count` in your query?

Comment: @user1834992 I just updated my answer (changed the order of the joins and select). Let me know if it works now

Comment: @user1834992 try removing the select option and modifying the order option like this: `order('COUNT(messages.id) DESC')`

Comment: tried the new way , when i put joins it gives this error : Association named 'messages' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?and includes gives an error as before

Comment: try with `.joins(:blogs_messages => :message)` in the join clause

Comment: It WORKS!!!!! the mistake was  .group('blog.id') , now that ive changed it to  .group('blog_id'), it works :) Thank you very very much MrYoshiji !!!

Comment: You are welcome @user1834992, I was pretty sure to be able to do this kind of request before ;)